iOS how to place VPN into "Personal VPN"? and .mobileconfig
In the VPN settings there is a section called "Personal VPN". It's interesting that these VPN can work simultaniously with the ones above. This is what I need - two VPN working at once.
I've setup VPN server and generated .mobileconfig file. I've read many sources and even official papers, but can't get yet - how to make it a "Personal VPN"?


Do you mean "Personal VPN"? Because that's what is in your screenshot

Oh, sorry - personal vpn, right
